# XSLT: XPath dynamically created with concat is not resolved

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract information from another section using a dynamically created XPath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
  <users>
    <user><id>1</id><name>Mars</name></user>
    <user><id>2</id><name>Merkur</name></user>
    <user><id>3</id><name>Venus</name></user>
  </users>
  <houses>
    <house><name>one</name><on>1</on></house>
    <house><name>two</name><on>3</on></house>
  </houses>
</doc>
```

I am using the following transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='doc/houses'/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='doc/houses'>
    <h2><a name="Houses">Houses</a></h2>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="100%" class="items">
      <tr class="items"><td width="40%">Name</td><td width="60%">On</td></tr>
      <xsl:for-each select='house'>
        <xsl:call-template name='writehouse'/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name='writehouse'>
    <tr>
      <td class="item-list">
        <xsl:value-of select='name/text()'/>
      </td>
      <td class="item-list">
        <xsl:value-of select='concat("/*/users/user[id/text()=",$apos,on/text(),$apos,"]/name/text()")'/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I am not able to make the

```
<xsl:value-of select='concat("/*/users/user[id/text()=",$apos,on/text(),$apos,"]/name/text()")'/>
```

work. Am I missing something? I get the following result

```
Houses
Name On 
one /*/users/user[id/text()='1']/name/text() 
two /*/users/user[id/text()='3']/name/text()
```

The path looks O.K. but it is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't construct XPath expressions dynamically like this in XSLT 1.0 without using a processor-specific extension, but in this case you don't need to as you can achieve what you require using the XSLT [`current()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/users/user[id = current()/on]/name"/>
```

`current()` provides access to the node that would be `.` if you weren't inside a predicate sub-expression.

I've also removed all the redundant uses of `text()` - you don't need them as you can simply compare the string values of the elements directly.  You very rarely *need* to use `text()` at all in most stylesheets, the only exception is where you really do need to consider each individual text node in isolation rather than simply working with all the text under an element.

Comment: @Totonga and in general, creating XPath expressions by string concatenation is a bad idea anyway as you risk running into quoting issues - XPath 1.0 string literals can be delimited by either single or double quotes but there's no escaping mechanism so it's impossible to put a single quote character inside a single quoted literal or a double quote character inside a double quoted literal.  A string containing both types of quotes can never be represented as a single literal in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian Roberts already explained, you cannot evaluate strings as XPath expressions in XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0), unless using an extension function supported by your specific processor.

In any case, XSLT has a dedicated **key** mechanism to perform data lookup. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="user" match="user" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="doc/houses/house">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="key('user', on)/name"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, would produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>Mars</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>Venus</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```